Can the Maven Versions Plugin work with the Polyglot plugin?
I'm wondering if the Maven Versions Plugin can be used in conjunction with the Polyglot Plugin to update versions when writing the POM in YAML. While I've successfully used YAML for my POM, I'm not sure if there's a way to integrate version updates through a properties file or another method. I'm even considering the possibility of generating a committed pom.xml and using it like a lockfile.

versions-maven-plugin works on pom.xml not on YAML files... and why not using the pom.xml instead of the YAML file...

@khmarbaise I feel like you misunderstood my question... perhaps you should ask why would someone want to use a yaml file instead of xml? that might be a good question for elsewhere. Then perhaps ask why someone would want to update their versions on request, effectively locking until upgrade.

Upgrading versions is of course a good idea but in the end using another format for a tool (Maven) which is pom.xml based.. and making it more complicated than necessary... does not make sense from my point of view... And what is the advantage using YAML?  And no there is no support (or more accurate not that I know) for an external properties file (properties can be defined in your pom file which most if the time is not needed) if using pom.xml (Also reconsider the warnings on the polyglot project: https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven?tab=readme-ov-file#limited-plugin-support

But what comes into my mind could be to use the .mvn/maven.config file and define some properties ? Might be way but I wouldn't recommend that...
